# Ethereum HD wallet library for Java

Tags: java, hd-wallets

Is there any Ethereum HD wallet java library? I find a popular java library on Github, [web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j), which doesn't support HD wallet yet.

Answer (score 1):

BitcoinJ does support HD wallet: [BitcoinJ HD wallet RestoreFromSeed](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/RestoreFromSeed.java)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by mixing `bitcoinj` and `web3j`:

```
String seedCode = "yard impulse luxury drive today throw farm pepper survey wreck glass federal";

// BitcoinJ
DeterministicSeed seed = new DeterministicSeed(seedCode, null, "", 1409478661L);
DeterministicKeyChain chain = DeterministicKeyChain.builder().seed(seed).build();
List<ChildNumber> keyPath = HDUtils.parsePath("M/44H/60H/0H/0/0");
DeterministicKey key = chain.getKeyByPath(keyPath, true);
BigInteger privKey = key.getPrivKey();

// Web3j
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privKey.toString(16));
System.out.println(credentials.getAddress());
```